# Why would node print Promise { <pending> }? Can I turn it off?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

Here is my test code to test calling of resolve callback in another callback embedded in promise constructor.

```
var p = new Promise(function (resolve) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        resolve('starbar');
    }, 3000);
});

console.log(p.then(function (v) {
    console.log(v);
}));
```

When running code in Node, it logged `Promise { <pending> }`.
Why would that happen and how to turn it off?

Comment: Just remove the outer `console.log()`? It's not clear what you want to achieve and why you are unsatisfied with the output.

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake to wrap useless console.log outside. After I removed the outer console.log(), things going well. Is the outer `console.log()` logging the immediate status of the promise object?

Comment: Yes, it's immediately logging what `then` returns - a not yet resolved promise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what happens when you log an entire promise, which is what you're doing here.

You don't have to turn it off, just stop logging the promise

```
var p = new Promise(function (resolve) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        resolve('starbar');
    }, 3000);
});

p.then(function (v) {
    console.log(v);
});
```

Comment: Oh! yes, I see. My fault. Thank you!